# Apt: find installed packages with given version number

Tags: linux, packages, version

I have just updated the kernel, meaning I have two sets of kernel files at the moment; and I'd like to use the command line to remove the old one.

I'm aware that I can use `apt-show-versions` to show which packages I have installed which are named `linux*`:

```
$ apt-show-versions -r linux*
libselinux1/natty uptodate 2.0.96-1ubuntu2
linux-firmware/natty uptodate 1.52
linux-generic/natty uptodate 2.6.38.10.25
linux-headers-2.6.38-10/natty uptodate 2.6.38-10.46
linux-headers-2.6.38-10-generic/natty uptodate 2.6.38-10.46
linux-headers-2.6.38-8/natty uptodate 2.6.38-8.42
linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic/natty uptodate 2.6.38-8.42
linux-headers-generic/natty uptodate 2.6.38.10.25
linux-image-2.6.38-10-generic/natty uptodate 2.6.38-10.46
linux-image-2.6.38-8-generic/natty uptodate 2.6.38-8.42
linux-image-generic/natty uptodate 2.6.38.10.25
linux-libc-dev/natty uptodate 2.6.38-10.46
linux-sound-base/natty uptodate 1.0.24+dfsg-0ubuntu1
pptp-linux/natty uptodate 1.7.2-6
syslinux/natty uptodate 2:4.02+dfsg-7ubuntu1
syslinux-common/natty uptodate 2:4.02+dfsg-7ubuntu1
util-linux/natty uptodate 2.17.2-9.1ubuntu4
```

From this I can see I have kernel files from `2.6.38-8` and from `2.6.38-10`.

Is there an apt command where I could specify something like 'version=2.6.38-8*'; and it lists all packages that match that version number (regardless of name)?

The reason I'm asking for this is that I'd like to be able to check if I have packages installed say with version `2.6.38-8*` - but which do *not* start with `linux*`.

I'm not sure if there are such files now, but I'm pretty sure I've had this problem before, which is why now I always first search for `linux*` in Synaptic, and then separately search for version number of the package I want to remove, and sort by installed, and remove all in one take. I'd just like to be able to do the same from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?:

```
apt-show-versions | grep 2.6.28-8
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Chris Acheson - the thing is, there could be packages that have `2.6.28-8*`, but do not start with `linux*`; thus, I'd like a "second pass", where I search only for version numbers like in Synaptic (this wasn't in the original question, but I added an edit to the OP). Thanks again, cheers!

Comment: That should find all packages by version number, regardless of name.  It takes the whole list from apt-show-versions, and filters out any lines that don't contain "2.6.28-8".  If you wanted to specifically not find packages that start with linux, you could do: apt-show-versions | grep 2.6.28-8 | grep -v ^linux

Comment: Indeed - sorry about that, @Chris Acheson, I misread your answer at first; accepted now :) Thanks - cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to use `aptitude` to perform fairly complex searches using its own built-in query syntax, e.g.

```
$ aptitude search '?version(2\.6\.38)'
```

See [the search section](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03.html) of the Aptitude manual for more information about the search syntax.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @OrbWeaver - I haven't used `aptitude` much (probably because a long time I read somewhere that I should use `apt-get` instead) - however, just tried it, seems to work :) Cheers!